# What is the best way to save my CSV's in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have currently setup a database where I store CSV's. I am reading more that CSV is bad practice in MYSQL.

My current setup is this:

```
    ----------------------------------------------
    |  id  |  Exercise  |  Set     |  Reps    |  date    |
    ----------------------------------------------
    |  1   | Value 1,   | Value 1, | Value 1, | 01/01/16 |
    |      | Value 2,   | Value 2, | Value 2, |          |
    |      | Value 3,   | Value 3, | Value 3, |          |
    ----------------------------------------------
```

When a user is submitting data they can have 'AS MANY' new 'Exercise' inputs (and in turn values) added as they want (there could be up to 50) but only 10 'Set' and 'Reps'. For example:

```
    <input name="exercise1[]">
            <input name="set[]><input name="reps[]">
            <input name="set[]><input name="reps[]">
            <input name="set[]><input name="reps[]">
    <input name="exercise2[]">
            <input name="set1[]><input name="reps1[]">
            <input name="set1[]><input name="reps1[]">
            <input name="set1[]><input name="reps1[]">
```

This is the way it currently works and is working fine but I want to know:

**Should I change they way I am storing this data?**

If so, I'm unsure how I should save it. **Is storing multiple rows for one form submission was a bad idea also?**

The only way I can see to allow 'UNLIMITED' exercise values without CSV's is the way below (which uses multiple rows per form submission) and setting up 10 columns in my database for each 'set' and 'reps'  (as I mentioned earlier there is only the possibility of 10 'Set' and 'Reps' values):

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |  Exercise  |  Set     |  Reps    |  Set2    |  Reps2  |  date     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Value 1    | Value 1  | Value 2  | Value 1  | Value 2  | 01/01/16 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Value 2    | Value 2  | Value 2  | Value 1  | Value 2  | 01/01/16 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Value 3    | Value 3  | Value 3  | Value 1  | Value 2  | 01/01/16 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me setup correctly before I go even further through my developing!

Comment: `"Is storing multiple rows for one form submission was a bad idea also?"` ... Yes, this is a bad idea, because now you have dangling records without a primary key.  Either store a single record, or add a key to the multiple records so they can be grouped if needed.

Comment: Easy. Don't. See normalisation

Comment: What do you mean 'Easy. Don't.' ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are always different designs. Pick one best suits your situation.

1 - Design in one table as per your example when you pretty sure the structure is not changing, eg exactly x sets and y reps etc

```
id, excercise, set1, set2, set3, rep1, rep2, ...
```

2 - If unsure in data when growing, you can design a meta table:

```
id exercise_id meta value
-- ----------- ---- ---------
1  1           set1 value1
2  1           set2 value2
3  1           rep1 value3
4  2           set1 value5
....
```

3 - One-Many relationship tables - the traditional method:

```
exercises (id, date, ...)
exercise_sets(id, exercise_id, value)
exercise_reps(id, exercise_id, value)
```

Comment: Thanks SIDU. How would I increment the primary key and apply to all rows. for example in your answer: 11, 11, 11

Comment: Would you suggest changing my current database structure? What if I inserted a group_id value?.

Comment: That could work, but all all exercises and sets and reps also need to be grouped by workout... So all inputs need to be grouped into one. e.g. 'workout_id = 1' for everything. Does that make sense?

Comment: Someone marks down on my reply, which makes me not interested in replying any more on this question :(

Comment: But I am stuck and need some assistance!

Comment: OK, where are you getting stuck? what is the question now?

Comment: As this answer listed most 3 common ways of designing, you can pick the best way meets your situation

Comment: Also save CSV into MySQL is not always bad idea, depends on what you are going to use it. if you are going to search part of the data, better save them in separate table or columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101240/discussion-between-sidu-and-taylor-made-pt).